# Access my system data which has private IP

Tags: storage, remote-access, private-ip

I need to give my laptop to someone for few days, i have my files in that out of which i'm not sure which one's i'll require. So looking for a solution if possible. How can i access those files by logging any time to that system either through remote or any other way. Everyone uses wifi router here, so each of the systems will have private IP(the one i'll use to access my system and the latter too)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option to install Teamviewer on your laptop and also on your other computer from where you will access.

Comment: i'll install and check .thanx